# Badges as motivation

Tags: discussion, badges

There is badges for some kinds of things. I used to only vote an answer up when I face a problem that the answer helped me. But some time later, I saw that some badges could be achieved by numbers of votes during a day and I started looking for questions in which I can vote answers up. I imagine that it is common scenario but I was thinking by myself that I was just doing that because of the badge, in a common day I'd never vote 40 times in a day for an example. I know it's very nice to receive a new badge but I would like to know if you agree that it's a good thing do something because of a badge. (I've already done many things prior knowing about badges, but for few cases I only started after knowing about that too).

Comment: The phrase you are looking for is "gamification".  The idea is to encourage positive interaction with the site by offering badges (and other things) as a reward for it.

Comment: he has an absolute valid point, receiving a badge after 40 upvotes makes you just vote for the sake of it.

Comment: In the same way, gaining rep for posting good answers may also make you post good answers. But then that’s exactly how SO works.

Comment: we should make change in the same like user adding comment or editing the question or answering it should be eligible to vote up some thing like that

Comment: Searching for 40 things which can benefit from a vote is good. Voting on the 40 things which just happen to be easiest to vote on is bad, I guess the good outweighs the bad across all the badges, else we wouldn't have them.

Comment: You just took my words. as m also seeing people are giving upvotes on even low quality question as to get first user first post and upvote and doing edit like one word change and all..because they need new hats and this is m afraid of as upvote means good qus and ans but now every new question is upvoted..god save SO :(

Comment: Maybe you prefer your glass half-full but the badges encourage *any* voting.  If you can't find 30 posts among the 12,000 questions every day that deserve a *down-vote* then you are not trying real hard.  Finding the extra 10 to upvote can be a bit of work.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your opinions guys. Interesting points of view.